# Use javascript variable into inlined code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, inline-code

How can I call a .net method in inline code using a javascript variable?
My code looks like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberIterations; i++) 
{ 
    var result = <%# GetFilterTagURL( myArray[i].Value, false) %>;
    //do stuff with result
}
```

This block is inside a javascript block; the GetFilterTagURL method is a a .net method and I want to pass the variable myArray[i].Value as the first parameter.

Any ideas?

**Update:**
All your answers are helpful. 
I guess that, as you say, I'll have to create a web service to achieve what I want.

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? If you want to loop `N` times in the code behind you will need to post this value to some handler, page or webservice and get the response value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send `client-script` values to the `server-side`. The oposite is valid though, you can register a javascript block from your `code-behind`.

See [`Page.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to accomplish it like that, since the `<%# %>` tag is used for Data binding.

One approach however would be to create a webservice and call it from your javascript. Inside your webservice you can then make the call to `GetFilterTagURL`and use the result in your javascript.

Check out [this article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

this will work, but you have to call `Page.DataBind()` in your code